# rxjs: caching different http-requests

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

**This question has been moved to Code-Review:**

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212854/rxjs-caching-different-http-requests

---

There have been multiple discussions on caching http-requests with rxjs, in this question/proposal I want to propose a custom rxjs-operator (non-pure) to provide caching:

```
const cacheHttp = (cacheKey: string, cacheStorage: any) => (source: Observable<any>) => {
  if (!cacheStorage[cacheKey]) {
    cacheStorage[cacheKey] = source.pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }
  return cacheStorage[cacheKey];
};
```

This operator is not pure, as it modifies one of its arguments (cacheStorage).

This operator could be used like this:

```
public cachedItems = {};

public getDataForItem$(itemId: string) {
    return this.http.get('/item/' + itemId).pipe(
        cacheHttp(itemId, this.cachedItems),
        shareReplay(1)
    );
}
```

The client could then call this multiple times without causing superfluous http-requests:

```
// the following two subscriptions cause http-requests
this.itemService.getDataForItem('firstItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
this.itemService.getDataForItem('secondItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));

// all further subscriptions would not cause any additional http-requests
this.itemService.getDataForItem('firstItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
this.itemService.getDataForItem('secondItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
this.itemService.getDataForItem('firstItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
this.itemService.getDataForItem('secondItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));

// this subscription would again cause an http-request:
this.itemService.getDataForItem('thirdItem').subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

**Now my questions:**
Is this an acceptable approach to solving the "cache-for-different-requests-problem"? Is there possibly a memory-leak or are there any leaked subscriptions? Is it ok to have side-effects on a provided argument?

Any comments or hints on problems with this custom-operator are very welcome!

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have a read of my article on ngx-RxCache library I wrote. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb